# The difference between EDOM and ERANGE in C?

Tags: c, errno

`errno` captures error messages from standard library functions. However, there are two macro values `EDOM` and `ERANGE` which I find hard to distinguish.

An example code from cppreference will do the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>

void show_errno(void)
{
    const char *err_info = "unknown error";
    switch (errno) {
    case EDOM:
        err_info = "domain error";
        break;
    case EILSEQ:
        err_info = "illegal sequence";
        break;
    case ERANGE:
        err_info = "pole or range error";
        break;
    case 0:
        err_info = "no error";
    }
    fputs(err_info, stdout);
    puts(" occurred");
}

int main(void)
{
    errno = 0;
    acos(+1.1);
    show_errno();
 
    errno = 0;
    log(0.0);
    show_errno();

    return 0;
}
```

and it will produce

```
domain error occurred
pole or range error occurred
```

So my question is: what operations will cause `errno` to become `EDOM`, and what operations will cause it to become `ERANGE`?

Comment: These are math functions that can be graphed: `y = f(x)`. Invalid values of the independent variable x will produce "domain" errors. Invalid values of the dependent variable y will produce "range" errors. Read the man page for each of the functions in the math library to learn what values will trigger an error (of which type) for each function.

Comment: I suggest replacing `show_errno` with the built-in function `strerror` - or use `perror` to print it directly..

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think I got my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ... what operations will cause `errno` to become `EDOM`, and what operations will cause it to become `ERANGE`?

> These are math functions that can be graphed: `y = f(x)`. Invalid values of the independent variable `x` will produce "domain" errors. Invalid values of the dependent variable `y` will produce "range" errors.  [@Fe2O3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75000827/the-difference-between-edom-and-erange-in-c#comment132354291_75000827)

*or*

> `EDOM` means the mathematical function is not defined there, and `ERANGE` means the computed function cannot give you the mathematical result because it cannot be represented in the result format.  [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75000827/the-difference-between-edom-and-erange-in-c/75001015?noredirect=1#comment132357576_75001015)

---

Both `EDOM` and `ERANGE` are defined in the C standard.

> For all functions (`<math.h>`), a *domain error* occurs if and only if an **input argument** is outside the domain over which the mathematical function is defined.  C17dr § 7.12.1 2

E.g. `sqrt(-1)`

> Likewise, a range error occurs if and only if the mathematical **result of the function** cannot be represented in an object of the specified type, due to extreme magnitude. § 7.12.1 4

E.g. `strtol("1234567890123456789012345678901234567890", 0, 0)`

Comment: More clearly. `EDOM` means the mathematical function is not defined there, and `ERANGE` means the computed function cannot give you the mathematical result because it cannot be represented in the result format.

Comment: @chux Very detailed and easy-to-understand answer